# Firefox 60+ Getting wrong element width

Tags: javascript, firefox, width

I'm getting different in Firefox 64.0 (Linux x64) than I am in Chrome 69.0, Opera 55.0, and Waterfox 52.2.6 (which I assume is very similar to Firefox 52) to get the width of an element.

The element in question has a width of 258px, and all of the browsers agree on this except for Firefox. Firefox seems to be getting the width of the parent container for some reason.

I've been using `.offsetWidth`, but I also tried using `.clientWidth` and `.getBoundingClientRect().width`, which all return the same metrics.

Debugging logging statement:

```
console.log(sampleElement,
            sampleElement.offsetWidth,
            sampleElement.clientWidth, 
            sampleElement.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

FF: `{element} 1024 1024 1024`

(the value changes according to the parent's width -- see below)

Chrome: `{element} 258 258 258`

Opera: `{element} 258 258 258`

Waterfox: `{element} 258 258 258`

where `{element}` is the HTML element in the console. In Firefox, interestingly, that representation is showing with the correct values for all of these width properties:

```
div.project-icon
  // ..
  clientWidth: 258
  // ..
  offsetWidth: 258
  // ..
  scrollWidth: 258
```

More information about the element:

- It is dynamically created, and inside a horizontally-scrollable flexbox, relatively-positioned container.
- The width that Firefox says it has is the width of the parent element plus 16px (but the parent element has no padding/margin).

Image of element in Firefox's Inspector:

[image]

I can't seem to reproduce the error in a snippet, but here is the code used to generate the element whose width I'm trying to get, and the code to get the width.

```js
let scrollContainer = document.querySelector('#project-scroller');
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
data.forEach((datum, index) => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('project-icon');
  div.dataset.index = index;
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    debounceScrollHandler(this);
  });
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  const images = ['https://imgur.com/BkvxnV5l.png'];
  image.src = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  div.appendChild(image);
  scrollContainer.appendChild(div);
});

let n = data.length;
let cur = Math.floor(n / 2);

// set to center
let sampleElement = scrollContainer.firstChild;
let sampleElementWidth = sampleElement.getBoundingClientRect().width + parseInt(getComputedStyle(sampleElement).marginLeft.slice(0, -2)) * 2;
scrollContainer.scrollLeft = Math.floor((sampleElementWidth * (n - (n % 2 - 1)) - scrollContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width) / 2);

console.log(sampleElement, sampleElement.offsetWidth, sampleElement.clientWidth, sampleElement.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

```css
#project-scroller {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
  
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}
#project-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.project-icon {
  flex: 0 0 258px;
  width: 258px;
  height: 258px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.project-icon:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
.project-icon > img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.project-icon.centered > img {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div id='project-scroller'></div>
```

**Update (from comments)**: My code works in FF versions 59 and earlier, but not 60 and later. Is this meaningful?

**Update 2**: I realized that if I set a small timeout (e.g., 10ms) and run the same code, the width is correct. Is it possible that there is some delay in getting the width from the CSS properties (the width is from the CSS class)?

Comment: `I can share more code if you need.` how about a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't seem to reproduce the issue in a code snippet here. Do you have any advice on how to proceed? I can't seem to think of a reason FF would give different values between the inspector and the JS values so I don't know where to start from here.

Comment: without seeing code (I mean HTML and CSS) that produces the inconsistency, I can't possibly guess what you've done wrong

Comment: having said that, if it is some bug in firefox 64, have you tried firefox 63 ... or the developer version, firefox 65

Comment: I tried every version since 59 (59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0), and it seems that 59.0 is the last version in which it works. The later versions all seem to have the same problem. I also tried version 50 (just to check that did indeed work before 59 as well), and it worked there.

Comment: so the cause is something you're doing somewhere which you can't identify (because you cant' reproduce in an mcve) but only since version 60 of firefox - which seems to be when *quantum css* was introduced to firefox - looking at the developer release notes, it may well be something [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/60#CSS)

Comment: @JaromandaX That does seem to make a lot of sense-- I'm guessing that it has to do with all the tricky parallelization optimizations they did, which means that perhaps the CSS styles aren't updated before the JS gets the value. I guess for now it's trivial for me to hardcode in this value but I'm not sure if this will cause problems in the future.